# Why doesn't Rey go back to Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker, rey, jakku

The whole movie from when Rey left Jakku, she keeps on saying "I have to get back to Jakku" and that she has already been away too long. I assume it is so that who ever dropped her there, that she is there when they come back???

However, in the end we see her searching for Luke Skywalker and there is nothing to suggest that she wants to get back to Jakku.

**Is there any information as to what changed her or her mind to not want or need to go back to Jakku?**

Comment: Just because she has a mission doesn't mean she still doesn't want to return to Jakku and find her family.

Comment: @curiousdannii, did you read the question? At every turn she is trying to get back to Jakku, but now she has time to deliver a lightsaber?

Comment: The whole movie serves as a coming of age arc for her character. The reason she doesn't go back to Jakku is the same reason Luke didn't head back to Tatooine at the end of A New Hope. They both knew there was nothing left for them in their old homes. Rey was "taking her first step into a larger world", to adapt Obi-Wan's quote to Luke.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Leia ordered her to go to Ahch-To to find Luke Skywalker. Rey feels that the Force is guiding her and that her decision (to go) is the right one.

> Rey headed to the launch area with R2-D2. Leia waited near the boarding ramp. She adjusted the fit of the new flight jacket Rey wore. “I’m proud of what you’re about to do.”
>   Rey looked into Leia’s eyes and saw more than pride. “But you’re also afraid. In sending me away, you’re…reminded.”             Leia let go of the girl’s jacket. “You won’t share the fate of our son.”
>   Rey glanced at the Falcon. Chewbacca had almost completed his exterior flight check. **“I know what we’re doing is right,” Rey said. “This is how it has to be. This is how it should be.”**
>   “I know it, too,” Leia said. “May the Force be with you.” She moved back and smiled as Rey boarded.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

and

> **She felt more alive than she ever had on Jakku. She had a destiny.** It
>   was big and frightening, but she had friends by her side to help her.
>   **Her life was only just beginning.**
>
> ...
>
> **Her life would never be the same. She might never return to Jakku. She might never reunite with her parents. Finding BB-8, meeting Finn, running into Han and Chewie—a series of accidents had led her there. This time, she wanted to make the choice.**
>   **“If it were you in my place, would you go?”** Rey asked.
>   Leia sat next to Rey and took her hand. **“That’s a decision only you can make.”** Leia paused for a moment, then continued. “But when you do decide to go—”
>   Rey began to protest, but Leia raised her hand. “Trust me, you will. And when you do go, promise me you’ll be careful.” She shook her head. “The Force is powerful. I know you must have sensed it when you fought Kylo. The temptation, the darkness can be…”
>   Rey didn’t need her to finish. She knew that Kylo was Leia’s son. The idea that the child of two such extraordinary people could fall to the dark side was frightening.
>   **But Rey would not let fear of the past stop her from embracing the future. Leia was right: Rey had a journey to go on.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey's_Story)</sup></sub>

Comment: Which takes hold of a seed planted earlier by Maz, when she told her: **"Whatever you've been waiting for---whomever---I can see it in your eyes, you've known it all along ... they're not coming back. But there's someone who still could. With your help."**

Answer (score 5):

Maz Tanaka, or whoever the oragange little alien was, told Rey that they both knew that no one was coming back to Jaaku for Rey.

Comment: It was Maz Tanaka, maybe you could elaborate the answer a bit more for those that have not seen the film

Comment: Really, and that says what?

Comment: @KyloRen It says that "the both know that no one was  coming back to Jakku for Rey". If she did indeed know that, there would no longer be a need for her to go back.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata